# Rails: Migration Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

when I go to my http://localhost:3000/ I am getting the following:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
>
> Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Extracted source:

```
# Raises <tt>ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError</tt> error if any migrations are pending.
def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
  raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
end
def load_schema_if_pending!
```

Also, when I tried to to the `heroku run rake db:migrate` in the console, it said:

> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation
>   "users" already exists

I am new to ruby and followed the  [devise tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WLPL1AvazE&index=22&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPK9Y4DRU-BiJtiY5L_QhUUq) by Mackenzie Child. It's my last step to complete my first ruby application.

I am excited and looking forward to your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used devise generator to prepare migration for your `User` model. Your model was already in place before and already had an `email` column. Devise-generated migration tries to create the same column and, expectedly, fails, that's the reason for the error you're seeing:

> PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR: column "email" of relation "users" already exists

To fix that just open your devise-generated migration and remove the line which looks something like this:

```
t.string :email...
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`.

**UPDATE**

Since your database seems to be out of sync with your migrations it might be advisable to recreate it from scratch.

Run

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Note that all database data will be destroyed.

Comment: I tried it and still get an error after rake db:migrate, which looks like this:

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: encrypted_password: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "encrypted_password" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'

...and so on

Comment: and also this instead: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "encrypted_password" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Comment: I pushed everything up to github (commits). Is there an easy way to restore everything from there?

Comment: Make sure this works locally first and when it does just push a new commit with the correct code state.

Answer (score 1):

In your console run `rake db:migrate`
Make sure you in the project directory

Comment: I might add, running `heroku run rake db:migrate` runs the migration on Heroku, not in your localhost. Errors like "PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR: column "email" of relation "users" already exists" usually come from modifying the migrations name or version.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. When I do that  I get: 
"rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:" Ater that: "SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL"
And then a lot of hundrets of lines about SQLite3 and activerecord